# ArcGIS 10.0 Python script won't recognize null

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, python-2.6

Has anybody ran into in issue where Python field calculations and/or scripts won't properly query Null (None) values?

The calculation I'm working on is a little more complex, but even the simple calculation below doesn't produce the correct results:

codeblock:

```
def test(field):
    if field is None:
        return "value is null"
    else:
        return field
```

expression:

```
test(!field!)
```

The result from above is:

```
input row 1 = <null>, output = <null>
input row 2 = "", output = "value is null"
input row 3 = "test value", output = "test value"
```

I can set value(s) in a field to null using:

Expression

```
None
```

I broke down the calculation I was working on in the Python Command Line to try to isolate how values were being interpreted.

```
>>> arg1, arg2, arg3 = "Testing", None, "this string"
>>> mylist = [arg1, arg2, arg3]
>>> remnull = [str(arg) for arg in mylist if arg]
>>> sep = " "
>>> finalval = sep.join(remnull)
>>> print finalval
Testing this string
>>> anullval = None
>>> if anullval is None:
...     print "yes"
...     
yes
>>> if not anullval:
...     print "yes"
...     
yes
```

It would appear that the Python Command Line is interpreting None correctly. Python scripts however won't recognize None values (using calculatefield_management or cursors), either as standalone script or script tool.

I've been doing a lot of coding lately.  I'm wondering if a rogue line of code hasn't corrupted something.

I can do a uninstall/re-install or repair but I'd like to spare myself a repeat if somebody knows the cause.

I'm on ArcGIS 10.0 SP5, Basic.  All data inputs are File Geodatabase.

Comment: Not really sure what you're doing here, but you could shorten you anullval test to: if anullval: print 'anullval has a value' else: print 'anullval has a null value'

Comment: @recurvata The issue here is part of a much larger process involving field calculations. I started to encounter issues and went to the python command window to breakdown my logic in the function. So that code is merely an example that Python command line will handle nulls correctly but nothing else will.

Comment: @hoss,If you share your sample data, others can validate this behaviour in their arcgis installation!

Comment: Are you attempting to assign NULLs to geodatabases or shapefile?  (Shapefiles don't support numeric or date NULLs, and can't distinguish between empty string and NULL.)

Comment: @FaridCher, I'd be happy to.  I'm not sure it's needed though.  The test function I cited won't even work.  Same issue persists involving any variation of that in field calculator or from Python IDE (stand alone or script tool) using calculatefield_management or cursors.

Comment: @Vince, file geodatabase version 10.0

Comment: I might add: in the type of work I do, I'm always manipulating attribute data and most manipulations require null tests/conditions.  Never had an issue before using 'None'.  I'm guessing the interpreter is hosed but I don't know why.  I can handle nulls using VB script.  It's just Python that started acting quirky.

Comment: I haven't run across this in either 10.1 or 10.2. Unfortunately I can't test 10.0. This sounds like [NIM059424](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDU5NDI0).

Comment: @EvilGenius, a bug at this point is about the only way I can explain it.  Thanks for sharing that.  So now that I'm about to join the world of 10.2.2, prepare for a bunch of data access cursor questions :)  Thank you all.

Comment: Whatever the issue, the problem resolved after upgrading to 10.3.1.  @EvilGenius, the bug you referenced is likely the cause I think.  The only thing that changed is my ArcGIS version and Python version.  The rest was same data and same script.  I didn't even modify the script, it worked as-is.