# Converting none to zero (0) in geodatabase table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser, error-999999, null

I have an attribute table looks like this

[image]

How do I convert Nulls into 0?

I've tried to set this table non nullable type but got this:

[image]

while the official doc says this:

[image]

At least one of them is wrong.

Then I tried many ways to do the job, like this:

```
RValues=arcpy.SearchCursor(sr)

for RValue in RValues:
    #print (RValue.getValue(field))
    if RValue.getValue(field) == None:
       #print (RValue.getValue(field))
       return 0
    else 
       return 
       float(RValue.getValue(field))

print(RValue.getValue(field))
```

This gives error 999999, don't know why, possible a bug.

Then I tried this:

```
RValues=arcpy.SearchCursor(sr)
print (RValues)

for RValue in RValues:
    if RValue.getValue(field) == None:
        print (RValue.getValue(field))
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(sr, "RValue",  esp, "PYTHON3")
    print (RValue.getValue(field))
```

Well, the first print gives a

```
<geoprocessing cursor object object at 0x0000025F5C161E70>
```

the second print does isolate all none items, as there is no null in python.

Here is the trick:

the third print either gives error or turn everything into null or 0,focus on everything, expressions I use are as follows:

```
esp="!RValue!.replace(None, 0)"

esp2="!RValue! * 0"

esp3="set field = 0 where field is null"

esp4="NVL(RValue,0)"

esp5="select nvl(RValue, 0) from sr.RValue"

esp6="None"
```

How is that even possible when the if before it already isolate only those nones?

Comment: also I've tried RValue.setValue(field,0) , also error 99999.

Comment: so many ways I've tried, either 99999 or apply to everything, other errors I've fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to replace Null values using Python parser of ArcGIS 10.0 Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165621/unable-to-replace-null-values-using-python-parser-of-arcgis-10-0-field-calculato)

Comment: Marking it as a duplicate won't delete the question or the answers, it just links them together so anyone that stumbles on this from Google or elsewhere will see the other question as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second version, you've mixed cursors and `CalculateField_management()`.  They don't work together in this way.  `CalculateField_management()` will change the value for ALL RECORDS*, and pays no attention to what is happening in your cursor.

You should use either an `UpdateCursor` (NOT a `SearchCursor`) OR use a `CalculateField_management()`.  Not both.

I usually do this sort of thing with just a `CalculateField_management()`. 
 You can do this in one of two ways:

**OPTION 1:**

This is quicker than OPTION 2 below (but I posted 2 first, so will leave it there as is).  This method only updates the records that need changing and also requires fewer lines.  I think it is somewhat easier to read too.

Firstly, either select just the records that you want to change to '0' OR make a feature layer that only includes those records.  I prefer the latter, as I feel safer (in the case the select doesn't work, you'll change ALL records; in the case the new feature layer doesn't work, you'll just get an error).

Then change all selected/layer records.

It's merely two lines:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(sr, "srLayer", "RValue IS NULL")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("srLayer", "RValue", "0", "PYTHON")
```

Although you may like to clean up afterwards by deleting the layer with a third line:

```
arcpy.Delete_management("srLayer")
```

**OPTION 2:**

Include a code block which will determine the correct value for all records.  Note that this will update records that don't need to be changed, but it will update them with the same value they already have, so not a big deal.

But this means that it is slower than OPTION 1 and also not as good for auditing purposes (eg, if you use editor tracking!).

```
codeblock = """
    def calcRValue(rvalue):
        if rvalue is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return rvalue
"""
arcpy.CalculateField_management(sr, "RValue", "calcRValue(!RValue!)", "PYTHON", codeblock)
```

**OTHER NOTES:**

Don't use `arcpy.SearchCursor` or `arcpy.UpdateCursor`, which have been superceded.  Use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` or `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`.  They are massively faster (even if marginally more difficult syntax).

I'm not sure what your first version is trying to do, but the last line (`print`) uses the variable `RValue` out of scope and I would not expect it to work there.  Perhaps it should be indented to be within the loop to print the value each time around the loop?  But I'm not sure what it's supposed to be doing there.

*actually, all selected records if there are any, or all records otherwise.

Comment: You're welcome.  :-)

Comment: that print there is to check the final result

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use an [UpdateCursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) to manipulate feature class attributes. However, make sure to use the modern Data Access `da` cursors. For example:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\featureclass'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "some_field") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == None: # None appears as <Null> in attribute table float fields
            row[0] = 0
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```